# How to Mention the Use of Pseudonym when Cold Pitching

Tags: planning, pseudonym, freelance

I'm looking to gain experience writing for blogs. To do this, I plan on cold pitching a list of bloggers with guest post ideas. Only, I'd like to publish the posts under a pen name. I don't want the pitches to get rejected because of that slightly unusual requirement, either.
I have no experience writing under that name and very little experience otherwise.
When should that I mention that I'd like to use a pseudonym? The second email, once they'd responded to my pitch? Or at a different time? 
When, where and how would you recommend I bring it up?

Answer (score 2):

It really is not that uncommon in an online world to use a pseudonym. You're doing it right now, in fact.

If you feel it is important to get settled early, though; still don't mention in the initial cold pitch. It is presumptuous, and it really does not relate to the content you are pitching, hence distracting from it.

Normally, you'd enter some sort of contract--or at least a work (for hire) agreement--and in the negotiation of that is when things like pseudonyms should first come up. If you don't expect to be compensated at all, it is also not entirely unreasonable to not treat it as a 'pseudonym' at all in your interactions, and to just sign your emails with it.

Comment: Is it a bad idea for future business with that person if I pretend a pseudonym is my real name? I mean, the other person might assume that the pseudonym is my real name, which could make me seem deceptive if I have to tell them later on that in fact, it's a pseudonym.

Comment: @user613 If you do not think you will want to keep using a pseudonym for your whole career, it may be best to avoid that, yes. If sums of money start exchanging bank-to-bank, same thing.